# Stored procedure to archive data older than 6 months (180) days

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We are trying to create a stored procedure to archive data older than 6 months (180 days) from our production database in to a new archive database.

We also want to delete those archived rows from the production database.

We are thinking to include a while loop, but we want to archive only 10,000 rows a day and we need to schedule it on daily basis.

Can you please share us your experience.

Thanks

Comment: Look into partitioning https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe delete into would work for you? Found something useful here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE
(
    ProductID INT NOT NULL
);

DELETE TOP (10000) ph
OUTPUT DELETED.ProductID INTO @MyTableVar
FROM Production.ProductProductPhoto AS ph
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, ph.YourDay, GETDATE()) > 180
--Display the results of the table variable.
SELECT *
FROM @MyTableVar
```

Comment: Thanks Evaldas, But we need to copy the old data in to archived database before we deleted it. Do you have some other option?